# Running Commandline

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to run a command from a window project using system() call but everytime the console shows up. how can i run the command without displaying a console window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `CreateProcess` function, and pass the flag `CREATE_NO_WINDOW`.